# Extract all Logical test condition used with IF statement (not nested) and print to separate column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of about 100 rows of formulas. Each row contains a cell which has 1/2/3/4/5/6 IF statements.

I need help to extract all of the logical test strings used for each row e.g. cell C2 contains:

```
=IF(Payload_Decode!AB74=Payload_Decode!Z92,"OK",IF(Payload_Decode!AB74=Payload_Decode!Z86,"OK",IF(Payload_Decode!AB74=Payload_Decode!Z87,"OK","ERROR")))
```

Input variable:

- E2 cell : *Payload_Decode!AB74*

Comparison variables in separate cells:

- G2 cell : *Payload_Decode!Z92*
- H2 cell : *Payload_Decode!Z86*
- I2 cell : *Payload_Decode!Z87*

I need this to happen to all rows. Here is a screenshot explaining:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've shown no attempt to solve this problem on your own, which is usually a requirement of this forum, but I found the issue challenging, so:

Since you have included a `VBA` tag, here is a User Defined Function, using Regular Expressions, that can do what you want.

The formula is an array formula.  If you have the latest version of Excel, with dynamic arrays, you can enter the formula in `E2` and the results will spill over to the right.

If you do not have that feature, you can display the results of the formula separately by wrapping in `INDEX`, or you can enter it as an array `E2:J2`

Please read the note at the beginning of the UDF regarding early vs late-binding.

'Set reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'  or use late-binding

```
Option Explicit
Function inputCompVars(ByVal S As String) As String()
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Const sPat As String = "\(([^=]+)=([^,]+)"
    Dim sTemp() As String, I As Long
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ReDim sTemp(0 To MC.Count)
            sTemp(0) = MC(0).SubMatches(0)
            I = 0
            For Each M In MC
                I = I + 1
                sTemp(I) = M.SubMatches(1)
            Next M
    End If
    inputCompVars = sTemp
End With

End Function
```

This is used with something like:

```
E2: =inputCompVars(FORMULATEXT($A2))
```

or, if you don't have dynamic arrays:

```
E2:  =IFERROR(INDEX(inputCompVars(FORMULATEXT($A2)),1,COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

and fill right as needed.

[image]

If you need a formula solution, and have Excel 2013+, you can try:

```
E2:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($A2),"=",","),"(",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'Payload_Decode')][1]")

F2:  =IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($A2),"=",","),"(",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'Payload_Decode')][" & COLUMNS($A:A)*2&"]"),"")
```

and select `F2` and fill right.

If you have earlier versions, you'll need to let us know which version.